# Executing an .exe from a shortcut with CodedUITest method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to add something to one of my tests but I cannot succeed.
Basically my test is going to desktop, double clicking an .exe and then close it.
And it works, but I need to execute that .exe file from a shortcut, for example i have the shortcut of that .exe file on my desktop and I want to access it.

This is my .cs code (part of it ) , it launches my UI map method

```
[TestMethod]
    public void LaunchPadTestMethod()
    {
        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        this.UIMap.LaunchPadOpen_Close();
    }
```

This is my UImap .cs method

```
public partial class UIMap
    {



        /// <summary>
        /// LaunchPadOpen_Close - Use 'LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams' to pass parameters into this method.
        /// </summary>
        public void LaunchPadOpen_Close()
        {
            #region Variable Declarations
            WinButton uIExitButton = this.UILoginWindow.UIExitWindow.UIExitButton;
            #endregion

            // Launch '%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\financialApp\financialApp\bin\Debug\financialApp.exe'
            ApplicationUnderTest uILoginWindow = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(this.LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams.UILoginWindowExePath, this.LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams.UILoginWindowAlternateExePath);

            // Click 'Exit' button
            Mouse.Click(uIExitButton, new Point(39, 16));

        }

        public virtual LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mLaunchPadOpen_CloseParams == null))
                {
                    this.mLaunchPadOpen_CloseParams = new LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams();
                }
                return this.mLaunchPadOpen_CloseParams;
            }
        }

        private LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams mLaunchPadOpen_CloseParams;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Parameters to be passed into 'LaunchPadOpen_Close'
    /// </summary>
    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.21005.1")]
    public class LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams
    {


        public  class GestCollURL
        {
            //------------------------------------------Class for getting current URL--------------------
            public static String getCurrentGestCollUrl()
            {

                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                //MessageBox.Show(path);

                path = path + @"\financialApp.exe";

                // MessageBox.Show(path);

                return path;
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }

        #region Fields
        /// <summary>
        /// Launch '%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\financialApp\financialApp\bin\Debug\financialApp.exe'
        /// </summary>

        // ORIGINAL !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //public string UILoginWindowExePath = "C:\\Users\\ExtremeSwat\\Desktop\\financialApp\\financialApp\\bin\\Debug\\financialApp.exe" +
        //    "";


        public string UILoginWindowExePath =  GestCollURL.getCurrentGestCollUrl()+
            "";

        /// <summary>
        /// Launch '%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\financialApp\financialApp\bin\Debug\financialApp.exe'
        /// </summary>
        ///

        //ORIGINAL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
       // public string UILoginWindowAlternateExePath = "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\financialApp\\financialApp\\bin\\Debug\\financialApp.exe";
        public string UILoginWindowAlternateExePath = GestCollURL.getCurrentGestCollUrl() + "";
        #endregion
}
}
```

I've created a class in which I have a static method where I find out the current desktop URL and then I concatenate my required executable.
And it works, but I need to execute shortcuts, for example the shortcut of financialApp.exe

EDIT 1

Changing from .exe to .ink or to nothing will cause my test to fail

EDIT 3 - Final working version, thanks to Simon's suggestions
This code block generates dinamically my desired url

```
 public class GestCollURL
    {
        public static String getCurrentGestCollUrl()
        {
          string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            //MessageBox.Show(path);
            path = path + @"\financialApp.lnk";
            return path;
        }
    }
```

This code overloads the Launch method

```
public static ApplicationUnderTest Launch(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
        {
            ApplicationUnderTest abba = new ApplicationUnderTest();
            Process launchPad = new Process();
            launchPad.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = startInfo.UseShellExecute;
            launchPad = Process.Start(TestingStuff.LaunchPadOpen_CloseParams.GestCollURL.getCurrentGestCollUrl());

            return abba;
        }
```

This is how I call it

```
(in the same class)
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            Launch(startInfo);
```

Comment: I don't have coded ui, but you should use this Launch overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd419605.aspx, and make sure you set UseShellExecute to true. It may work just using the simple ProcessStartInfo constructor with the path as parameter.

Comment: please check out my question, I have a problem with my overloaded function, I get an error( look upper) and when I look over the function I see 0 references.....help ?

Comment: Do you happen to rest your hand on the enter key when not writing? O_o

Comment: I am sorry, had some code blocks that I have removed earlier because they were unnecessary, I've cleared out the empty spaces (most of them)

Comment: +Simon Mourier please update it as an answer, It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this Launch overload: [ApplicationUnderTest.Launch Method (ProcessStartInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd419605.aspx). It allows you to specify exactly how you want to launch the application under test.

Just make sure you set [UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) to true somewhow because links and shortcuts are shell (explorer) objects that cannot be started like normal exes.

> When you use the operating system shell to start processes, you can
>   start any document (which is any registered file type associated with
>   an executable that has a default open action) and perform operations
>   on the file, such as printing, by using the Process object. When
>   UseShellExecute is false, you can start only executables by using the
>   Process object.

It may work just using the simple ProcessStartInfo constructor with the path as parameter, depending on your context.